# It would take a miracle, which is what we do here?

Tags: the-princess-bride

Is it a good chance, neutral or remote chance when his wife asks, "Do you think it'll work?". He responds "It'd take a miracle".

Since he is in the business of miracles (or because his name is miracle max) does that indicate confidence? Or, just because of the word miracle which indicates very rare is it a very remote possibility?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I think it is meant as ironic humor.

Comment: [That's the joke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xECUrlnXCqk)

Comment: in the movie, he's played more as a con man - and that, as Steve-O said...is the joke. In the book, Max and Valerie are played a bit more straight in terms of their profession (but still just as comedic) and that miracle making is a valid science. In the book, the line is Valerie saying to Max [Max having just lamented that he should have doubled the dosage]: "the pressure you've been under, if it works at all, it will be a miracle" - but earlier Valerie tells Max he should take the case because "you've always been good at dead, they all come back: every time"

Answer (score 1):

His tone of voice would seem to indicate he thinks they have a snowballs chance in hell, at least that was always the way I took it.

There really is no way to say for certain though.